# How to put item1 in first row and item2 in second row in grid-area-template?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GG25KMYLJOZU

```css
    .item1 {
      grid-area: myArea1;
    }
    
    .item2 {
      grid-area: myArea2;
    }
    
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-areas: 'myArea1 myArea1 . . ' ;
      grid-template-areas: 'myArea2 myArea2 ' ;
      
      grid-gap: 10px;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .grid-container > div {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px 0;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1">1</div>
      <div class="item2">2</div>
      <div class="item3">3</div>  
      <div class="item4">4</div>
      <div class="item5">5</div>
      <div class="item6">6</div>
    </div>
```

There my aim was to put `item1` in first row's first two columns and `item2` in second row's first two columns.

**What is the way to achieve that?**

Please explain why item1 is sitting at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your CSS

Firstly, you seem to be requiring 5 columns but this only defines FOUR..

```
grid-template-areas: 'myArea1 myArea1 . . ' ;
```

and should be

```
grid-template-areas: 'myArea1 myArea1 . . .;
```

*then* the second area line **overrides** the first statement...which is why, originally, your `item1` was misplaced

What you are after is:

```css
.item1 {
  grid-area: myArea1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: myArea2;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  
  grid-template-areas: 
  'myArea1 myArea1 . . .' 
  'myArea2 myArea2 . . .';
  
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
</div>
```

PS: OP now states that there should be 4 columns rather than 5 implied in linked W3Schools code....so adapted accordingly

```css
    .item1 {
      grid-area: myArea1;
    }

    .item2 {
      grid-area: myArea2;
    }

    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      grid-auto-rows: auto;
      
      grid-template-areas: 
      'myArea1 myArea1 . . ' 
      'myArea2 myArea2 . . ';
      
      grid-gap: 10px;
      background-color: #2196F3;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .grid-container>div {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px 0;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell `Firstly, you seem to be requiring 5 columns ` which piece of code shows that 5 columns are required.

Comment: Your link specifes that there are five columns... *"Item1, is called "myArea" and will take up the place of all five columns:"* Perhaps you changed your requirement?

Comment: Well, actually, that statement is from that link. I haven't written it. I don't completely understand what they are doing there.  `grid-template-areas: 'myArea1 myArea1 . . '` I wrote it deliberately because I thought this would be the way to have item1 span 4 columns. And item2 span two columns.

Comment: Moreover they haven't shown any `repeat` function over there. Please show how it can be achieved like the way they have shown - without any repeat. Also, thank you for showing the new way of doing this using repeat.